# Help with understanding SQL stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL and am now working with stored procedures.
I was watching another developer's code and I saw this statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [deleteRecords_UNICODE]
@RecordIDs ty_NumberList READONLY
```

Question 1: What does the "ty_NumberList" mean?

Question 2: I'm creating a stored procedure that needs to use the above parameter.
When I created "DECLARE @RecordNum int", I obviously got the error of

```
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with ty_NumberList
```

I'm guessing I have to resolve this by:
a) Creating a variable of type "ty_NumberList"
b) then go with my usual DECLARE @RecordNum int
c) Then pass the value of @RecordNum into ty_NumberList

Question 3: How would I go about implementing the above steps in SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ty_NumberList` is the type of a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

You would use it like

```
DECLARE @Nums AS ty_NumberList;

INSERT INTO @Nums VALUES (1);

EXEC YourProc @Nums;
```

Comment: what about that code makes it a table value parameter?  without seeing the CREATE TYPE statement couldn't it be any user defined type?

Comment: The `READONLY` is mandatory for TVPs (not sure if it is even valid for other datatypes but in any event its presence and the name of the type would indicate TVP to me)

Comment: @AL W: After viewing the CREATE TYPE, I can confirm that it is indeed a TVP. Thanks for the note about the READONLY, @Martin.

Answer (score 1):

That code is using `Table-Valued Parameter`s, read up on it in Books On Line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> **Read this**
>
> ty_number means you have to tell us
> because its a user defined data type
>
> while declaring the stored procedure
> parameter
>
> we no need to use declare
>
> create proc sample @name vanchar(20),
> @num  varchar(20) Begin
>
> Select ........ .......
>
> End